# Can a totally jammed power lock be caused by the motor?

Tags: locks

The power locks on my vehicles have jammed totally.  You can deform it a little bit by pressing really hard, otherwise, the bits of the lock mechanism won't move at all.  However, they are attached to a motor.

The lock elements themselves don't look to be attached in such a way that is very removable, so it makes me wonder if the motor might be the part that is actually suck cold.  The only way to test it appears to be to remove it totally, however.  I bought the car mostly like this; also, I hit the mechanism with P oil pretty thoroughly and it has no effect.

(I have an endoscope if anyone thinks posting a video of it would help.)

1993 Ford Tempo

Comment: 1993 Ford Tempo - The only way to get the motor out appears to be to drill out the rivet, and I'm not sure how to test the latch theory (the handle seems to operate normally)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can and does on that model, you would need to remove or replace the motor to get things working again.

Closest video I could find:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWoB7Uhxd9c